# $* is not supported

Tags: perl

I have a code in Perl:

```
sub PrintVariables {
  local (%in) = @_;
  local ($old, $out, $output);
    $old = $*;  $* =1;


 $output .=  "<DL COMPACT>";
  foreach $key (sort keys(%in)) {
    foreach (split("\0", $in{$key})) {
      ($out = $_) =~ s/\n/<BR>/g;
      $output .=  "<B> $key = </B>$out <BR>";
    }
  }
  $output .=  "</DL>";
    $* = $old;
  return $output;
}
```

in which `$old = $*;  $* =1;` and `$* = $old;` gives error that $* is no longer supported. What should be the replacement for those two lines. I don't know the perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Man, that's some ancient code.  It appears to predate lexical variables, which means it's Perl 4 code.

In this case, `$*` isn't actually doing anything.  Just remove it.

```
sub PrintVariables {
  local (%in) = @_;
  local ($out, $output);

  $output .=  "<DL COMPACT>";
  foreach $key (sort keys(%in)) {
    foreach (split("\0", $in{$key})) {
      ($out = $_) =~ s/\n/<BR>/g;
      $output .=  "<B> $key = </B>$out <BR>";
    }
  }
  $output .=  "</DL>";
  return $output;
}
```

It's supposed to globally turn on the `/m` regex flag.  But the only regex used by that code doesn't contain anything that's affected by `/m`.

Comment: Bottomline, i just have to remove those 2 lines yes?

Comment: In this case, yes.  They aren't necessary for the current code.  It's likely a previous version used a different regex.  When somebody changed the regex so that multiline-matching was no longer relevant, they forgot to remove the `$*` bit.

Answer (score 7):

To get a more verbose explanation of the warning message, `use diagnostics;`

> (D deprecated, syntax) The special variable $* , deprecated in older
>   perls, has been removed as of 5.9.0 and is no longer supported. In
>   previous versions of perl the use of $* enabled or disabled multi-line
>   matching within a string.
>
> Instead of using $* you should use the /m (and maybe /s) regexp
>   modifiers. You can enable /m for a lexical scope (even a whole file)
>   with use re '/m' . (In older versions: when $* was set to a true value
>   then all regular expressions behaved as if they were written using
>   /m.)

Answer (score 6):

From `perlvar`:

> `$*` was a variable that you could use to enable multiline matching.  After a deprecation cycle, its magic was removed in Perl v5.10.0.  Using it now triggers a warning: "$* is no longer supported".  You should use the "/s" and "/m" regexp modifiers instead.
>
> Deprecated in Perl 5.

In other words, that script is ancient, full of bad practices (even for the time), and – worst of all – there is no need for multiline matching *at all*.

Just remove all lines referring to `$*`, and it should still work. Otherwise, add the `/m` modifiers to all regexes in that region.

Comment: "and it should still work" ...because the patter uses neither "^" nor "$", the only two things affected by /m.